# setFetchBatchSize Fetching all the rows in messages Table

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Following is my code snippet.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortSequence = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                                      initWithKey:@"date_added" ascending:YES];
 NSArray *sortDescriptors =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortSequence,nil]; 
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:5];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
[NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@“Chats”];
NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"messageSectionKey" cacheName:@"Chats"];
```

In my listing I want to implement load more functionality. I want to sort based on the key `date_added` . `messageSectionKey` is a getter method in the coredata class which will return *Yesterday,Today etc* based on  `date_added` … But After fetching instead of loading 5, it is loading all the rows in my `Message` table

Answer (score 0):

I guess to get the 5 objects you should set the fetch limit as 5

```
[fetchRequest setFetchLimit:5];
```

To get say 20 records , you pass in the parameter value of numberOfItems = 20, do your working inside a function, its just an idea , you can make your own function, I guess you should use only fetchLimit

```
-(void) getRecordsFor:(NSInteger) numberOfRecords {
....

 [fetchRequest setFetchLimit: numberOfRecords];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
[NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@“Chats”];
...
}
```

Comment: setFetchLimit will work. But for load more functionality we should use setFetchBatchSize

Comment: @Jeff I guess you need to use both, setFetchBatch size will only keep the objects in memory, but to get the array of 5 objects you shouls use fetchLimit

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Then how I will load the previous set of messages (load earlier messages)

Comment: @Jeff I modified the answer, I think you can do it like this, hope it helps

Comment: Then How will I load the 2nd set of messages.

Comment: @Jeff I guess you would give it the value of 10 to get the next five messages also, but I havent implemented this so this can be one option

Comment: Nope. In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644744/core-data-iterate-over-fetchrequest-in-chunks-with-setfetchlimit-only-processing they are saying using both are redundant

Comment: @Jeff I think your problem can be solved using only fetchLimit, you just need to maintain the count of requests, if requestCount is 1 , send the parameter in above function as requestCount * 5, it will fetch 5 record, if requestCount is 2 , send in the paramter as requestCount * 5, it will bring in the second 5 records also,

Comment: It won't help me. As the listing is real time . New messges are coming  and inserting in the the table view. So indexes are going beyond the bounds